# Is it possible to save Windows NT credentials to reuse them later?

Tags: windows, security

I have a testing program through which employees can submit JAR files to be executed. This is obviously a security concern, and it gets even worse as the executables have to be trusted since they normally need to access enterprise data.

To that end, I was wondering if it was, at least, possible to use the Windows account of the employee sending the JAR to execute it instead of some surrogate account. Is it somehow possible? What would it imply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look into the [SSPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Support_Provider_Interface) functionality of Windows, which may allow you to transparently transfer an authentication token so that you can execute the JAR in the context of the user.

Comment: Would it work if I needed to save those credentials and wait until later?

Comment: It won't let you authenticate later, but that's the closest I think I can get to.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you submit the credentials of the user passing in the JAR file, the saved credential wil not work later on.  You might be able to execute it immediately, as long as the sending machine and executing machine are one hop away.  Otherwise, the credential will not travel any farther.